# prose.io "not found" error message

Tags: github, jekyll, github-pages, prose

I'm trying to use prose.io to create a templating engine - specifically to save markdown files to a github repo that then are immediately rendered.

I'm playing around with prose.io on their online editor to try to add markdown files to a previous Jekyll static page, but when I'm trying to commit a new file, there is a "not found" error on the icon where you commit the changes.

[image]

If anyone has had this error before I would appreciate the help!

Comment: I am also having problems adding files to my own project (not a shared one as above). I can edit files but not add new ones that get rendered on the site.